# Wordpress: Query child pages content while on parent pages

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I have custom post types setup - called projects and enabled child pages. While I am on the parent page, I want to query the content of the child pages on the parent page.

Here is my attempt. This queries ALL custom post types called projects. Can anyone help me query the child pages?

```
<?php

$args = array(

    'child_of' => $post->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'projects', 

    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$wpq = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $wpq->have_posts() ): while( $wpq->have_posts() ): $wpq->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">
            <?php echo the_content();?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. Hopefully anyone else having this question will find this! I found the wordpress codex for get_pages: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

```
<?php $children = get_pages( 
    array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'projects',
    ));

foreach( $children as $post ) { 
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="section-container">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can change this to draw content from a particular page's children as well by changing $post->ID to the numerical ID of the desired parent page. Ex

'parent' => 10

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$query = array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '3','orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC');


                $loop = new WP_Query($query);

            if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>
                    <div class="section-container">
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ); ?>
                    </div>


            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```